# Binding problems between an usercontrol and its parent (another usercontrol) MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties, caliburn.micro

I am creating an  UserControl with 2 RepeatButtons and one TextBox. So problems begin when i want to Bind some properties....

FYI i am using Caliburn.micro as Framework..

- i need to have the value of property Interval from the parent to define the time lapse of both repeat button
- i need to have the MaxValue defined in the parent and use it in the event MouseClick of customcontrol
- i need to initialize the value of TextBox of custom control from parent, use it in the event mouseclick of custom control to obtain the new value update the TextBox and use the new value changed in the parent...

what i have tested:

**CustomRepeatButton.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace ChromiumWPF.UserControls
{
    public partial class CustomRepeatButton : UserControl
    {
        public CustomRepeatButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty TextValueProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("TextValue", typeof(string), typeof(CustomRepeatButton));

        public int IntervalValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(IntervalValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IntervalValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty IntervalValueProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("IntervalValue", 
                                       typeof(int), 
                                       typeof(CustomRepeatButton),
                                       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, 
                                                                     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
                                      );

        public int MaxValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("MaxValue", typeof(int), typeof(CustomRepeatButton));
    :
    :
    //same definition for ResetValue, MinValue and IncrementValue

        private void RepeatButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // click on button + or - and change the value of TextValue i trap in usercontrol Parent
            var RB = sender as RepeatButton;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**CustomRepeatButton.xaml** (see Bindings TextValue and IntervalValue in Style)

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChromiumWPF.UserControls.CustomRepeatButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChromiumWPF.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Consolas"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aquamarine"/>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding TextValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="RepeatButton">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Interval" Value="{Binding IntervalValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="RepeatButton_Click"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
   <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RepeatButton Content="-"  />
            <TextBox />
            <RepeatButton Content="+"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

**ChromeViewModel.cs**

```
private string adress;
public string Adress
{
    get { return adress; }
    set 
    { 
        adress = value; 
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Adress); 
    }
}
private int _test;
public int Test
{
    get { return _test; }
    set
    {
        _test = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Test);
    }
}
private int _maxV;
public int MaxV
{
    get { return _maxV; }
    set
    {
        _maxV = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MaxV);
    }
}
```

---

**ChromeView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChromiumWPF.Views.ChromeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:ChromiumWPF.UserControls"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChromiumWPF.Views" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ChromiumWPF.ViewModels" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ChromeViewModel}"
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1200">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox x:Name="Months" Background="Aqua" Height="30" Width="100"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

            <uc:CustomRepeatButton TextValue="{Binding Adress}"
                                   IncrementValue="10" 
                                   IntervalValue="{Binding Test}" 
                                   MaxValue="{Binding MaxV}" 
                                   MinValue="900" 
                                   ResetValue="1080" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So i have problem with Test, Adress and MaxV (`only Bindings in relation with the customControl`).

I dont see why the bindings is in error, the definition of DP and properties seems ok for me?? is it a problem of DataContext?  Maybe i have to set the DataContext to ChromeViewModel? if yes how i could do that?... Thanks for help..

**errors displayed:**

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Adress' property not found on 'object' ''CustomRepeatButton' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Adress; DataItem='CustomRepeatButton' (Name=''); target element is 'CustomRepeatButton' (Name=''); target property is 'TextValue' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Test' property not found on 'object' ''CustomRepeatButton' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Test; DataItem='CustomRepeatButton' (Name=''); target element is 'CustomRepeatButton' (Name=''); target property is 'IntervalValue' (type 'Int32')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MaxV' property not found on 'object' ''CustomRepeatButton' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MaxV; DataItem='CustomRepeatButton' (Name=''); target element is 'CustomRepeatButton' (Name=''); target property is 'MaxValue' (type 'Int32')
```

Comment: Just as a temporary test, put a `TextBlock` in ChromeView.xaml, right next to the `CustomRepeatButton`.  Try to bind its Text property to 'Address' as you do for the `CustomRepeatButton`.  Do you get the same binding error?  I know you said *only binding in relation with the custom control*) but I just want to be sure.  If you do get the same error, then you've got a DataContext problem with ChromeView or there is relevant code you might not be showing.

Comment: Incidentally this is not a "custom control".  it is a `UserControl`.  I am not trying to be anal-retentive here but the difference is important.

Comment: @Joe i have created a TextBox with just name `Adress`  and Caliburn does the job (to bind) and yes its okay

Comment: and have yes  you have right, i am working on UserControl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF the dependency property system uses value precedence. For example, the `DataContext` value of a `FrameworkElement` is implicitly inherited from the parent. If you set the value explicitly you will override the inherited value (the parent's `DataContext` will be ignored by the property system).

In general you want a custom control to inherit the parents `DataContext` so that external data bindings assigned to the dependency properties.

The external `Binding` uses the current `DataContext` as source (implicitly):

```xml
<UserControl>

  <!-- Binding expects the DataContext of CustomRepeatButton 
       to be of type ChromeViewModel -->
  <uc:CustomRepeatButton TextValue="{Binding Adress}" />
</UserControl>
```

The following local `Binding` overrides the inherited `DataContext` value (taken from your code):

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ChromiumWPF.UserControls.CustomRepeatButton"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

</UserControl>
```

Because of this `Binding`, the `DataContext` of `CustomRepeatButton` is the `CustomRepeatButton` control itself. Every `Binding` that uses the implicit binding syntax (`{Binding path}`) will now bind to the `CustomRepeatButton`. This explains the error message that states that the source object is of type `CustomRepeatButton` : *"BindingExpression path error: 'Adress' property not found on 'object' ''CustomRepeatButton'"*.
This also exemplifies why you should never set the `DataContext` of a custom control explicitly - unless you want to surprise the user of your control.

To fix this don't ever set the `DataContext` of custom control explicitly. In order to bind the internals to the control's properties you must use the proper binding source i.e explicit binding source.

If the internals are assigned to the `Content` property of a `ContentControl`, for example of a `UserControl`, you must use `Binding.RelativeSource` and set the [`RelativeSource.AncestorType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property of the `RelativeSource` extension:

```xml
<UserControl>
  <RepeatButton Interval="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=IntervalValue}" />
</UserControl>
```

Bindings are the same when defined in a `Style`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="RepeatButton">
  <Setter Property="Interval" 
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=IntervalValue}"/>
</Style>
```

If the internals are defined inside a `ControlTemplate`, you would have to use the [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) extension (instead of `Binding`) or use the `Binding` extension and set the `Binding.RelativeSource` property using the [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) extension and set its [`RelativeSource.Mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) property to [`RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#fields):

```xml
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CustomRepeatButton">
  
      <!-- Recommended using the TemplateBinding extension -->
      <RepeatButton Interval="{TemplateBinding IntervalValue}" />

      <!-- Using the Binding together with the RelativeSource extension -->
      <RepeatButton Interval="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IntervalValue}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your  answer, i have to read slowly and test to understant...!!  `one`, i have to put off the definition of `Datacontext` from the `CustomRepeatButton.xaml` file, `two` do you mean my approach with binding inside Style is not good?  i have to use ControlTemplate?  so i need time to read this new concept for me...

Comment: 1) correct 2) No, i was trying to say that binding to the DataContext is wrong. You must design your control like there is no DataContext. Instead bind directly to the properties of the custom control. I showed two scenarios: a) the control is a UserControl and the layout is defined as Content (like in your case) or b) the layout is defined as ControlTemplate. Because the Style for the RepeatButton is applied in the original context (the location in the visual tree), you define the bindings like you would define them locally. Just use `RelativeSource.AncestorType` as shown in my example.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how the binding looks inside a Style (it looks the exactly the same).

Comment: The `TwoWay`  binding on `RadioButton.Interval` is redundant. `RadioButton` will never change the `Interval` property value. Otherwise it would have been configured to bind `TwoWay` by default.

Comment: You can (and should) write `<Style> <Setter ... /> </Style>` instead of `<Style> <Style.Setters> <Setter ... /> </Style.Setters> </Style>`  like you don't write `<UserControl> <UserControl.Content> <RadioButton /> </UserControl.Content> </UserControl>` but the compact form `<UserControl> <RadioButton /> </UserControl>`.

Comment: This works because the `Style` class has defined the `Setters` property as content property (`[ContentProperty("Setters")]`). When you decorate your class with the ContenPropertyAttribute you can define the property that the XAML value of the root is assigned to. In this case every `Setter` that is direct child of the `Style` root tag will be implicitly assigned to the `Setters` collection. For `UserControl` the attribute is configured as `[ContentProperty("Content")]` to implicitly assign the child node of the root to the `Content` property.

Comment: For example, if you configure your CustomRepeatButton class to use the TextValue property as content property (`[ContentProperty("TextValue")]`), then the following text *"example text"* would be implicitly assigned to the `TextValue` property:   `<CustomRepeatButton>example text</CustomRepeatButton>`.

Comment: [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks)

Comment: Thank you for the pedagogy of your answer. Your answer is very complete and very interesting and it allows me to improve and understand WPF even more. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple.  You are trying to make the control's XAML bind to its own dependency properties but you are doing it the wrong way.  You need to set the DataContext on the *first visual element within the control*, not on the control itself.

So do this:

First, go to your CustomRepeatButton.xaml file.  Go to line 8 (shown below) where you set the `DataContext` to itself.   Delete that line

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Next go to the first visual element.  The `Grid`.  Give it an `x:Name` value so you can refer to it in code-behind.  Like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" ShowGridLines="True">
```

Finally go into the control's code behind constructor.  Manually set the `DataContext` right after the call to `IntializeComponent`.  So make it look like this

```
public CustomRepeatButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainGrid.DataContext = this;
}
```

That should get you what you want.